# What is my MacBook's public IP address?

Tags: wifi, network

I am trying to find out my public IP address for my MacBook Air  It is on Comcast/Xfinity Wifi (my parents had some tech dudes set it up). When I check http://ipecho.net or any other I get 73.170.168.215, but this is the same as on my iPhone 8.

On the contrary, the two devices have different local ip addresses with all the numbers the same except the last one 192.168.40.XXX. Is the public IP address the same thing as the router?

Comment: The public IP you found is probably correct - all devices in your home will share it. Your secondary question is far too broad - punching a hole in a domestic router to give access to a specific service on a specific machine is far too complex to answer in a couple of paragraphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP you're seeing (73.170.168.215) is the address your router is exposing to the outside world.  The router is masking you're real address to keep you safe.

Any device that uses that router to connect to the outside world will be 'seen' as having that same IP.  This is why your Mac and your iPhone appear to have the identical IP's when viewed from outside your network.  The public IP  is the address of that router (I'm trying to keep this simple because networking can get really complicated fast).

Your router is responsible for taking the individual device traffic and routing them to the correct device **within** your "private" network.

To use BlockheadsServer correctly with your Mac, it's best if you contact their support to determine the best way to configure it.  You don't want to misconfigure a router because you might accidentally open-up your network to malicious activity.

Comment: Okay thanks for confirming that it is the router making all of the public IP's look the same. If I'm going to get the "real" IP address of my MacBook I will confirm with the tech dudes how best to change this settings (and confirm with my parents if it's ok to do so).

Comment: @cmarangu What your router is doing to translate between internal (private) and external (public) addresses is a form of [network address translation (aka NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). You can find lots more information using that as a search keyword/phrase.

Comment: It's always important to get your parents permission first!  :-)

Comment: When you say "real" IP address of your MacBook - what are you referring to; what are you trying to do?  Your MB has an IP (a private one) and your router has two (public and private).  The question is...what are you trying to accomplish that you need this info?  (probably a new/different question)

Comment: @Allan I need to find my "real" public IP address (not the one my wifi shows to all websites) to let my friend who does not live in the same house as me (consequently he is not on the same wifi) to access my server which is being hosted from my specific MacBook. Also, I am using the server port 15151 it is the recommended one.

Comment: I have found a discussion bout something like this in a different context on another StackExchange site:https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109112/how-to-find-public-ip-if-it-replaced-by-nat-ip I still am not sure how I will find my un-NAT'd public IP address though...

Comment: Yet another disappointment "by normal means no..." https://superuser.com/questions/63124/is-it-possible-to-get-the-nat-ip-address

Comment: You need the public IP of your *router*, not your MacBook.  Your router will then [port forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) the port you referenced (15151) to your MacBook.  Further, you will want to use [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service since your public IP will eventually change.  All that said, this basically makes it off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Some routers allow for Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) which will allow the application that you are running on your mac to request port forwarding to "expose" the application to the internet. This will allow the router to be the proxy on the edge of your network and then route the require ports through to your mac on your home network. This is a great way (if your application and router supports this function) as you do not need to spend ages in the router config setting up all the ports and forwarding.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. It seems that the neatgear router does support it! according to their webpage, but I am wondering if I only need to port forward the port Im using in the app 15151 well, I guess we shall see.

Answer (score 1):

It says [here](https://forums.theblockheads.net/t/how-to-set-up-your-own-mac-server/3080) that you may need to setup port forwarding to allow incoming connections from port 15151 to your Mac. If your dad lets you, you may be able to try this in the router settings.

Comment: It worked! Turns out it was just the port forwarding setting for the specific use of the specific app after all.